# Pull request from feature branch into test branch shows changes that are already inside test branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, merge, branch

Using azure devops, I was merging a feature branch into test with some new changes.

I am not yet fluent in git, so my process is always via VS Code git options for merging, pulling and pushing and when I have new changes in feature branches that can go into test branch, I always create a pull request via azure devops.

However, in my current situation, in pull request there are changes listed for files that already exist in destination (test) branch. For example, FileA was merged from feature branch into test branch 2 weeks ago. I now made some changes to FileB and in the pull request, it shows that the FileA will also be merged into test branch, even though it already exists in test branch. I am not the sole developer and there were several commits into test already, but I can't pinpoint the exact problem neither in my commits, nor in others. As I said before, FileA was merged into test 2 weeks ago and now it shows up in pull request again, even though FileA was not deleted in any commit inbetween and I can still see FileA in test branch when I open up the source files on azure devops.

What could've happened here and what can I do?

Comment: sounds like you are squash-merging things into the target branch. Is that the case?

Comment: @eftshift0 when merging from a feature branch into test branch, I do a merge (no fast-forward).

Comment: But is it a _squash_ merge? Or a real merge?

Comment: @eftshift0 it is a real merge, because when completing a pull request I can choose to do a no fast-forward merge (that is what I always have selected), or I can choose squash merge, and also some other merge types.

Comment: Is there any chance you are rebasing stuff (the wrong way, that is)? If you rebase commits that are already merged, then that also explains what you are seeing.

Comment: @eftshift0 nope, didn't do any rebase on any branch.

Comment: That the same changes appear again means that the same changes happens in 2 different nodes in the history of the 2 branches. This means that some kind of rebasing must have happened at some point. Could be a squash-merge, a cherry-pick, or a regular rebase.

Comment: That's right.... those are the usual suspects. Check the history of the branch that you are trying to merge since you diverged from the target branch..... those changes will show up there in some commit (or commits).

Comment: If you want to inspect what has happened you should look into the history of the 2 branches. Try running `gitk branchA branchB` (eventually add an & in the end to make the command non-blocking) and search after the file which the changes has appeared in. It can also be helpful to run `gitk branchA branchB path/to/file`

Comment: @eftshift0 I think I figured out what happened. I merged the master branch (this is the prod branch) into my feature branch and then made a pull request from feature branch into test branch, which is why it showed all the changes from feature branch instead of just a few changes.

Comment: You might want to answer that question yourself then.

Comment: Glad to know you have figured out what happened! In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you can put your answer and accept it in the reply. In addition, i can also reproduce the same with you if i use `squash merge` when completing DevOps pull request with the steps shared. Thanks.